# Terraform - is local ran before or during the resource call

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

For terraform, resource, is the local ran after or before the resource is called?

The reason being, when my local is ran in the below code, not all the resources in the `aws_vpn_connection.VPN-CONN` are ready, so my `tga_vpn` is not complete, and thereby, not all resources are created in `aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation` resource

I have to run terraform apply again to add the remaining resources.

```
locals {
  tga_vpn = flatten([
    for vpn_conn in aws_vpn_connection.VPN-CONN: 
    .
    . 
])
}
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation" "TGW-RT-PROP" {
  count = length(local.tga_vpn)
  something1 = lookup(local.tga_vpn[count.index], "id1", null)
  something2 = lookup(local.tga_vpn[count.index], "id2", null)
}
```

I also added depends on `aws_vpn_connection` in the `aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation` resource, but that did not help.

Or is there a way to add `depends_on` for local?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know roughly how long it takes for the `aws_vpn_connection` to be fully initialized and ready to use after its creation, you can use [time_sleep](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep) resource to delay execution of your `aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation`.

For example, assuming it takes 30 seconds, you could do:

```
resource "time_sleep" "wait_30_seconds" {
  depends_on = [aws_vpn_connection.VPN-CONN]

  create_duration = "30s"
}

resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation" "TGW-RT-PROP" {
  count = length(local.tga_vpn)
  something1 = lookup(local.tga_vpn[count.index], "id1", null)
  something2 = lookup(local.tga_vpn[count.index], "id2", null)

  depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_30_seconds]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin. 
My terraform plan shows the same number of resource creation despite of adding count of 10 mins

Comment: @VinitaShah Did you apply it? TF plan does not account for time delay.

Comment: @VinitaShah No problem. Glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the Terraform language itself, each local value is itself a node in the dependency graph and so your resource's references to `local.tga_vpn` already tell Terraform that `aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation.TGW-RT-PROP` depends on everything that `local.tga_vpn` depends on. Likewise, the local value refers to `aws_vpn_connection.VPN-CONN` and so the chain of dependencies here is:

- `aws_vpn_connection.VPN-CONN` might have some other dependencies, but we can't see those in your partial example
- `local.tga_vpn` depends on `aws_vpn_connection.VPN-CONN`
- `aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation.TGW-RT-PROP` depends on `local.tga_vpn`.

Given this, if you are seeing the actions for `aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation.TGW-RT-PROP` happen before the actions for `aws_vpn_connection.VPN-CONN` are complete then unfortunately that suggests a problem either in the AWS provider or in the remote AWS API. Despite the AWS provider's efforts to work around a lot of cases, some objects in the AWS API are "eventually consistent", meaning that there isn't a guarantee that you can write a new object and then immediately try to use it. Instead, the change might take some time to be fully visible to all other parts of AWS, because AWS is a distributed system.

In that sort of situation, if the AWS API offers no way to explicitly determine when an object is *actually* fully proagated then unfortunately we are forced to use workarounds such as the `time_sleep` resource type that Marcin described, which doesn't actually *solve* the problem but it at least makes it less likely to occur by giving longer for the remote system to achieve consistency than would be true if Terraform just naturally began working on the downstream object immediately when its dependencies became ready.